# Gatsby + Contentful - how do I redo GraphQL query locally without restarting my server (npm run dev)?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I've just started with Gatsby + Contentful using their "Launch onboarding button" and the starter repo at git clone https://github.com/contentful/starter-gatsby-blog.git. I am familiar with React but not very familiar with GraphQL or Contentful.

When I make an edit to my content at https://app.contentful.com/, I restart my server (`npm run dev`) in order to query for those changes, but that takes quite a few seconds.

Is there a faster way to redo the GraphQL query during local development, without having to restart my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby exposes an environment variable called `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT`. If it's set to `true`, it exposes a webhook under `/__refresh` that can receive `POST` requests to refresh the sourced content.

So basically, if you change your running command to:

```
"develop": "ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true gatsby develop",
```

You can trigger a `http://localhost:8000/__refresh` locally to refresh your content. Alternatively, for a more automated way you can create a command like:

```
"refresh": "curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh"
```

You can check for further details at https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/refreshing-content/

Comment: thanks! oddly enough I had already accepted someone else's answer to this q (same suggestion as you) but it seems they have deleted it...so the points are yours now. ty :)